# Add an item from a query to a form

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm on Access 2010.

I'm designing a database to help keep track of participants in a community program.

I have a table called `ParticipantMaster` that includes fields like `ParticipantID, FirstName, LastName, Address, Phone`, etc and an entry form built on this table.

I have a set of forms/tables that collect attendance data (with levels to show whether they attended PARTIAL, HALF, or FULL session)... the fields relevant to my question here include `ParticipantID` (from Participant Master), `WorkshopID`, `Level`.

From the attendance data I've created a query called `Attendance_FullorHalf` that counts how many Half or Full sessions each participant has attended.  Fields include `ParticipantID`, `CountStatus`, `FirstName`, `LastName`.  This query is working correctly.

Separate from attendance, I have a table and form called `Interviews` that logs every time I call a Participant.  They only become eligible for interviews after their attendance Count > 2.

I want the attendance count to display on the interview logging form so I can see right there whether they are interview-eligible.

Maybe a text box that displays something like

```
SELECT CountStatus from Attendance_FullorHalf 
WHERE ParticipantID (from Attendance_FullorHalf query) = ParticipantID (of the record I'm on in the interview form)
```

I know it's probably not a statement like that that I need -- I just wrote that to help explain my question.

So if I'm in the interview form, entering info on participant whose ID  is  20-563 I want it to display on that form how many sessions participant number 20-563 has attended.

Hope my question is clear -- thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Surely in the forms oncurrent event you can write a query that pulls the attendance figures for that participants ID and then update a textbox with the result of the query.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT FOLLOWING FROM COMMENT BELOW:

create a text box on the interview logging form

create an onCurrent event for the form and choose code builder
you should have a window that looks like below

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

End Sub
```

into this you'll need to write your code... something like this should give you a starting point to work from

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim rs as DAO.Recordset 'recordset object to hold the results of the sql query
    set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("INSERT YOUR SQL HERE")
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then 'we have a value for this participant
        txtBox.Text = rs![FIELDNAME] 'update the textboxes text value
    Else
        txtBox.Text = "0" 'else no value means 0
    End If
    set rs = nothing ' clean up the recordset after we've finished with it
End Sub
```

now the above is VERY VERY rough and dirty but the principle is fairly sound. open recordset, run your SQL against it, if the recordset now has results then update the textbox with those results.

hope that helps get you started

Comment: No, I don't think you're missing anything... I think you get what I'm trying to do.  I'm just not sure where or how to actually do that.  Where do I enter that query & how do I get it to show up on that form?  On current event gives me the choice to build an event through macro/expression/code builder.  I don't see a place to write in SQL (which is what I know best).  I'm not sure how to use those builders and how to then  get them to show up in a text box.

Comment: i've updated my answer to hopefully give you a decent starting point

Comment: THANKS --  I also did some more investigation on my own and came up with this, which seems to work:  I created a text box and used this expression builder    `=DLookUp("CountOfStatus","Attendance_FullorHalf","[ParticipantID] = Form![ParticipantID]")`    ............

Comment: well.. if it works, then dont fix it! personally I'm working on upgrading a number of older access 2003 apps to 2010 atm and the various DCount/DLookup functions are the bane of working life! but thats a question/rant for another post ;)